# What is this ring-shaped part falling from Starship SN9 after launch?

Tags: spacex, engines, identify-this-object, spacex-starship

[image: Text]

The picture shown is a screenshot during the recent launch of SpaceX's SN9 from a live stream, and I noticed that a black ring fell off the exhaust/engine. It only shows up for around a frame or two and I couldn't find any related information on it. My question is what that was?

Comment: Interesting. This could be related to the engine failure. Or, it could be completely unrelated :-D Roadside rocket science is fun.

Comment: It's clearly not [bird shaped](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20275/12102). The 2nd stage F9 Merlin engines have [rings at the end of their much longer and vibration-prone vacuum nozzles](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20700/12102) that keeps them from vibrating too much, but I don't think that this could be anything like that.

Comment: Maybe it's an o-ring falling off something closer to the camera and not actually in the plume? Something in the plume would have been moving extremely fast. Can you give a video link and time?

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for the responses. I actually found this in a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwZl6YV3xYA&t=300s) by Scott Manley. You can see this frame at around 5:01 on the lower right.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got the original, less-annoying-than-Manley video from SpaceX's website and extracted a bunch of frames around the one you show. Unfortunately this didn't show any other positions of the object. My guess, but only a guess, is still that it's not in the plume.

Comment: if it was really moving that fast, its amusing to not get draggy smudgy image of whatever it is

Comment: It looks like a drop of liquid.